# Laravel 5 - Edit Checkbox values that exist in database

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

Evening,

Having a late night mind blank here. I am trying to edit a form that will allow you to change the category you initially assigned the blog post to.

I need to display each category with a checkbox like this and check the category that is already selected.

cat1 [ ] cat2 [ ] cat3 [x]

In my view I have this part in the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p><b>Which category do you wish to assign this post to?</b></p>    
        @foreach (App\Http\Models\BlogCategories::all() as $category)
            {!! Form::label('category_name', $category->name) !!}
            {!! Form::checkbox('categoryId', $category->id, null, ['class' => 'field']) !!}
        @endforeach
</div>
```

This works up to the point it displays each category with a checkbox, what I now need to do is change the 3rd parameter of the checkbox (currently null) so that on each iteration of the loop it checks whether

```
$category_id == $post->category_id
```

and set the 3rd parameter to true.  Or at least I think that is what I am missing?

Comment: Can't you just simply throw an if statement into your foreach to actually check for $category_id and then set the third param of checkbox to true?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it does not appear to like that"? Do you get an error, or does nothing gets checked?

Comment: I would not rule it out, If I put this right after the foreach line if ($category->id == $post->id) {true}  else {false} endif it does return the correct true/false albeit not as a checkbox, however if I put it in as the 3rd argument it returns and unexpected '<' error which would indicate it was expecting more or different from the if statement.

Comment: Try to put it into the third param like this 
    {{($category->id == $post->id) ? true : false}}

Comment: I tried that however it's the same error.  Quite annoying the logic is right, it's the way of getting the format right as a parameter, I may need to try that without enabling blade as part of the form build.

Comment: That is what i was thinking as well how about
    

<input type="checkbox" {{($category->id == $post->id) ? " checked" : ""}} />

Comment: Thanks David, we were at the same point there, removing blade and reverting back to basic form syntax worked perfectly.  Thanks for your support there, appreciated.

Comment: Your welcome Holo, have fun and make sure to get some sleep ;-)

Comment: @Holo You didn't have to do all that. You could've just replaced the third parameter with `$category->id == $post->id`.

Comment: Ok, I was an idiot, again people, don't work on an issue late at night!  @KemalFadillah you are correct that was all that was required and I had tried that.  The issue was actually more simple.  I was using the wrong variable.  $category->id == $post->category_id is what it should have been.  I was trying to match the category_id against the id of the post which was never going to work!  Apologies all.